# Imported module binding not working with DOM created element in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

In my project `home.page.ts`, i have codes that can create a `<video></video>` tag element onto HTML through a div with an id `<div #videoContainer></div>` after compiled.

e.g: `this.video = document.createElement('video'); //will create <video> tag in HTML`

furthermore, i also have a module NgxFaceApiJsModule imported inside `app.module.ts` that can bind into an attribute in HTML  tag and produce detection output.

in my HTML, if i do straight using `<video allFaces></video>` it will work and give output. However if use `<div #videoContainer></div>` (later will replaced by  after compiled) it will not work. how can i solve this?

## home.page.ts

```
  @ViewChild('videoContainer') videoContainer;

  private video: HTMLVideoElement;

  constructor(
    public facedetect: NgxFaceApiJsModule,
  ) {

    this.video = document.createElement('video');
    this.video.setAttributeNS(null, 'allFaces', '');
    this.video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
    this.video.height = 480;
    this.video.width = 640;
  }
```

## app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), NgxFaceApiJsModule.forRoot({ modelsUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/master/weights',}), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    MediaCapture,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AndroidPermissions,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

## home.page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div #videoContainer></div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: then you should show us the part where you're inserting the html into the div

Comment: @Ramesh sorry for that, because i was in rush earlier, now added the home.page.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the interface `AfterViewInit`

```js
class HomePageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

     @ViewChild('videoContainer') videoContainer;

     private video: HTMLVideoElement;

     constructor(
       public facedetect: NgxFaceApiJsModule,
     ) {


     }

     ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       this.video = document.createElement('video');
       this.video.setAttributeNS(null, 'allFaces', '');
       this.video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
       this.video.height = 480;
       this.video.width = 640;
       this.facedetect.detectAllFaces(this.video);
     }
}
```

Comment: tried implemented it inside ngAfterViewInit() but still couldnt make it work. there was no output of detection

Comment: I guess you added the line: facedetect.detectAllFaces(this.video). 
I edit the answer with this line.

Comment: adding the facedetect.detectAllFaces(this.video) would not work also as that property doesnt exist in NgxFaceApiJsModule. this the link of that module i used here [link](https://github.com/kamiazya/ngx-face-api-js) . it will also run if i did not declare it in the constructor. it will detect and produce output in img or video tag. but on my case, not working.